# Not able to Generate more than one graph in jquery using for loop

Tags: jquery, flot

I am not able to generate more than one graph(flot chart) dynamically using for loop in jquery. it's generated only one chart . I mentioned the code below.

```
datedealsdata = "Any data "
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    $('#head').html('<div class="leadConvCycle'+i+'"></div>')
    var datedataset = [{ data: datedealsdata, color: "#21abf6" }];
    $.plot($(".leadConvCycle"+i), datedataset, options);
    $(".leadConvCycle"+i).UseTooltip();
}
```

html code:

```
    <div id="head"></div>
```

Comment: Is it generating for `.leadConvCycle2`?

Comment: i jus mentioned for example.. i jus want to generate 3 graphs . But it's generated last graph only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
datedealsdata = "Any data "
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   var datedataset = [{ data: datedealsdata, color: "#21abf6" }];
   var ele = $(".leadConvCycle"+i);
   generateGraph(ele);
}
function generateGraph(ele) {
    $.plot(ele, datedataset, options);
    ele.UseTooltip();
}
```

[See working example like this](https://jsfiddle.net/gkmmr1b8/1/)

Comment: @PythonTeam I have added a fiddle example in my answer you must check this

Comment: it's working.. Sorry now i have edited the question above.. i have edited the code above. The above edited code is not working . Can you please tell the solution

Comment: You need to use this `$('#head').append('<div class="leadConvCycle'+i+'"></div>')` instead `$('#head').html('<div class="leadConvCycle'+i+'"></div>')
`@PythonTeam